# Q: Selecting og:image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, meta

I'm selecting my faceboook og:image with javascript with:

```
$('head').append('<meta property="og:image" content="calculatedImageURL">');
```

I can see that the tag appears in generated source but no in source code (before JS), of course. The problem is that the image i selectd is not appearing in facebook and with the facbook debuger i see this error:

```
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```

The cuestion is: is it possible putting the **meta og:image** in body? I know that w3s says we shouldn't but i've not access to change the head content.

Sorry for my poor English ;).
Thanks.

Comment: `i've not access to change the head content` - why not? by the way `<meta>` is not an image, so your question makes zero sense

Comment: i've not access because i'm using Oracle WebCenter Sites and the meta is calculated on a fragment and i only ave access to change the JSP part that is printing the "event". The <meta property="og:image"> is used to say to Facebook, twitter, ... which is the image you want to be printd in a link to this event. In my case the event is this one: http://www.azkunazentroa.eus/az/ingl/activities/concert-rosalia-y-ra%C3%BCl-refree/al_evento_fa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending a meta tag to HTML on client side won't work for you. Crawlers such as google, facebook and twitter will not read those meta tags. These tags should be placed in your generated HTML file on server-side.
By the way, if you want to change a meta tag:

```
$("head meta[property='og:image']"); // select meta tag using this jQuery selector
```

Comment: ok. i supposed it but I whould rather ask. So that jQuery sentence wouldn't work either?

Comment: Unfortunately no, crawlers won't wait for anything. They just scan your HTML dom and leave your page. They have millions of requests to answer.

Comment: @EndikaHernando I'll be glad if you accept my answer if it helped.